# How to compare the second values of a Pair

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, compare

I've got the generic Pair class and I want to be able to compare just the second parameter between two pairs.

I saw this solution posted but the problem is that I don't know how to instantiate this. Can someone help me with this or tell me how I can implement a different method.

```
public class Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime> {

    private Machine machineNo;
    private ProcessingTime processingTime;


    public static class MachineNoComparator <Machine extends Comparable<? super Machine>, ProcessingTime>
    implements Comparator<Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime>>
    {

        public int compare(Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime> pair1,
                Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime> pair2) {
            return pair2.getMachineNo().compareTo(pair1.getMachineNo());
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from just the code you've given us -- is `Pair` actually generic?  It doesn't look like `MachineNoComparator` should be generic, it looks like you should just have `class MachineNoComparator implements Comparator<Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime>>`.

Comment: Did you mean this to be a generic type? `Machine` and `ProcessingTime` are somewhat odd as type parameter names...

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry for the confusion. Pair is a class that I created and by generic I meant that's a class that is usually used to create Pairs. Think of it as this. And I want to be able to compare the S values between two pairs. 

public class Pair<F, S> {

 F first;
 S second;
}

Comment: @LouisWasserman If I use class MachineNoComparator implements Comparator<Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime>>, then I won't be able to use the .compareTo() method from the Comparator. Any fixes for this ?

Comment: @Gana: Is `Machine` a specific class that is `Comparable`?  How is `Machine` defined?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Machine and ProcessingTime are both Integers. This is how it's defined:  List <Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();

Comment: Then why aren't you either calling them integers, or creating a `Machine` class that contains an integer?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm sorry I'm not sure if I completely understand. Could you give me an exmaple ?

Comment: If by `Machine` you mean `Integer`, then don't write `Machine`, just write `Integer`.  If you want a separate type, then write `class Machine implements Comparable<Machine> { int machineNo; }` and have an actual class.  Right now it sounds like you're trying to hack `Machine` to be an alias for `Integer` and that's messing you up.

Comment: @LouisWasserman OK so this is what I have got so far:

class MachineNoComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{

 List <Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList;
 
 public MachineNoComparator(List <Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList){
  this.pairList = pairList;
 }

And when I try to instantiate:
 public List <Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();

 MachineNoComparator comparator = new MachineNoComparator(pairList);


I'm getting an error that I cannot instantiate with this type. Why ?

Comment: Why does the `Comparator` have a `List`?  The `Comparator` shouldn't really have any fields; the `Comparator` might be separately passed to `Collections.sort` to be used to sort a `List`, but the `List` doesn't belong inside the `Comparator`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman No because I've got a method inside the comparator class to compare the values between two pairs:

 public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> pair1, Pair<Integer, Integer> pair2){
  return pair2.getMachineNo().compareTo(pair1.getMachineNo());
  
 }

This is basically what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.  That shouldn't have anything to do with having a `List` inside the `Comparator`?

Comment: That's a good place to start.  Fields in `Comparator`s should generally only be things that tell you how to do the comparison, like other `Comparator`s or maybe `Function`s in Java 8.

Comment: What do you want to use it _for_?  Do you want the list to be sorted relative to the `Comparator`?  Then call `Collections.sort(pairList, new MachineNoComparator())` to sort the list.  The list isn't a _property_ of the `Comparator`; the `Comparator` is being _used to sort_ the list.

Comment: What do you want to use the `compare` method _for_?  You can always do `new MachineNoComparator().compare(pair1, pair2)` anywhere you want, with elements from the list or otherwise.

Comment: Please post the complete code that is getting you that error, and the complete rest of the error message.

Comment: public List <Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();new MachineNoComparator().compare(pair1, pair2);
public abstract class MachineNoComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> pair1, Pair<Integer, Integer> pair2){
return pair2.getMachineNo().compareTo(pair1.getMachineNo()); 
} 
}
public class Pair<Machine, ProcessingTime> {
private Machine machineNo;
private ProcessingTime processingTime;
public Pair(Machine machineNo, ProcessingTime processingTime){
this.machineNo = machineNo;
  this.processingTime = processingTime;}